# how to match text and other match condition from different column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, index-match

looking for a formula that can give me an index value after matching text then also meet a match condition from another column
I was using following formula, but I need now to add another condition of matching additional value from another column, so two conditions are to be met I presume.

```
=INDEX(F$7:F$11,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$6:B$13,B13)),0))
```

***problem:***
[image]

also tried this formula but it also giving the same result

```
=INDEX(F$7:F$11,MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$7:G$11,"AAA"))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$7:G$11,"GGG"))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$6:B$13,B6)),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(a,XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(A1&" "," ")&"*",E$1:E$5,E$1:F$5,{"",""},2),IF(DROP(a,,1)=B1,TAKE(a,,1),""))
```

Or, maybe just spill down results:

```
=BYROW(A1:B8,LAMBDA(x,LET(a,XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(TAKE(x,,1)&" "," ")&"*",E1:E5,E1:F5,{"",""},2),IF(DROP(a,,1)=DROP(x,,1),TAKE(a,,1),""))))
```

[image]

Comment: =LET(a,XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(B6&" "," ")&"*",F$7:F$12,F$7:G$12,{"",""},2),IF(DROP(a,,1)=C6,TAKE(a,,1),""))

is there a way we can separate column F$7:G$12, as in actual data both columns are in separate sheets?

Comment: Possibly include `HSTACK()` to yell them together @MuhammedTabish

Comment: have applied
=LET(a,XLOOKUP(TEXTBEFORE(B6&" "," ")&"*",F$7:F$12,HSTACK(F$7:F$12,G$7:G$12),{"",""},2),IF(DROP(a,,1)=C6,TAKE(a,,1),""))

but now the issue coming is TEXTBEFORE condition, whereas the matching text could be at any place in a cell.